# Dynamically changing linktext in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have a scenario where **Lintext** will change dynamically.I tried with a string variable like below and it is not working. It is giving the error message - The value for annotation attribute FindBy.linkText must be a constant expression.

```
@FindBy(linkText = strLinkText) 
private WebElement DName;
public WebElement lnkDName() {
return DName;   
}
```

How to handle dynamic link text? I already tried xpath which is also not working.

Comment: Share the anchor tag and little bit Outer HTML.

Comment: Please add some HTML, to add better perspective. And You cannot add dynamic text to @FindBy annotation. Try by finding parent element which is stale, and get child (this dynamic element) from it.

Comment: <div class="table-responsive" _ngcontent-c8="" style="height: 24px;">
<table class="table" _ngcontent-c8="">
<tbody _ngcontent-c8="">
<tr _ngcontent-c8="">
<td _ngcontent-c8="" align="left">
<td _ngcontent-c8="" align="left">PC</td>
<td _ngcontent-c8="" align="left">SHK</td>
<td _ngcontent-c8="" align="left">Test1923</td>
<td _ngcontent-c8="" align="left">20186515_192612657000_dl-Test1923</td>
<td _ngcontent-c8="" align="left">Active</td>
<td _ngcontent-c8="" align="left">
<td _ngcontent-c8="" align="left">
</tr> 

The linkText is Test1923

Comment: @RJM : I do not see any anchor tag though ! how are you using partialLinkText() or LinkText()

Comment: driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Test")); should do the job

Comment: @pburgr : update your answer with that ! a cssSelector to the anchor tag would have been stable as he said it's dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If at least part of the link text is always the same, you can fint it by partialLinkText

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(String));
```